# Retrieve cookies from remote host and pass them back to client

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm trying to grab cookies from a remote host with a little script which works well:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, TRUE);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$opt = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

I would like to know how I can pass them back to the client?

Comment: I just want to send the cookies back to the browser.I will be very grateful if anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Wheres the cookie in your code?